# How to attach different events on multiple selectors through .on function in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two elements as following on my page:

```
<input type="text" id="textfield"/>  
<input type="button" id="button" value="CLICK"/>
```

And in my Javascript code I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
     $("#button,#textfield").on("click change",function() {
           // This won't work because I don't need click function 
           // to be worked on the text field 
     });
});
```

What I need is click function to be worked on button and need only change function to be worked on text field. How do I do this?

Comment: write separate function where to do all actions, and just trigger it on each separate event..

Comment: You can test a condition within the function which type of input you clicked, instead of this try to give as separately its easy to understand and read.

Comment: I need to work this in a single .on function , dont want to declare multiple functions, how to do this

Comment: see my answer then. it handles single function code.

Comment: dineshkani gave me almost what i needed , i just wanted to minimlize the code

Answer (score 3):

If you want the same code to be called for different events on different objects, you can put the event handling code into a common function and then specify the exact conditions in each event registration:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    function myEventHandler(e) {
        // your code here
    }

    $("#button").on("click", myEventHandler);
    $("#textfield").on("change", myEventHandler);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Split your code into:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
     $("#button").on("click",function(){

     });
     $("#textfield").on("change",function(){

     });
});
```

Why did you put them together?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
     $("#textfield").on("change",function(e){
         my_function(e);
     });

     $("#button").on("click",function(e){
         my_function(e);
     });

     function my_function(e){
        // e = event...
        // your actions...
     }
});
```

Comment: OKay ,so we have to give two .on functions to fullfill this scenario right ,thank you

Answer (score 0):

Seperate to two function:

```
 $("#button").on("click change",function(){
     // Handle button
 });

 $("#textfield").on("change",function(){
     // Handle Textfield
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign them separately:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    //button code here
});

$('#textfield').change(function(){
    // text field code here
});
```

If you want them to do the same thing, create a separate function:

```
function doSomething() {
    // text field and button code here
}
```

and then reference that function instead:

```
.click(doSomething);
...
.change(doSomething);
```

Also, i should tell you, "change" does not do what you would think for a text field. It does not fire while typing, only when you "blur" the text field after updating it. It's more for checkboxes and things of that nature. I would use [.keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)

Comment: okay thank you , i intented was after typing the textfield and when tabbing to the other element

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this if you want only one .on function

```
$("#button,#textfield").on("click change",function(){
 if ($(this).attr('type') == "text"){
       alert("Do your change function");
 }
 else if ($(this).attr('type') == "button"){
    alert("Do your click function");
 }
});
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/9Fm2k/)

Comment: Okay this is the minimalized code i think , i will accept this ,thank you