# Allowing for multiple selectors within one function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down box in which allows for a "category" to be selected, if it is changed it loads the new category as shown in the code below. I have since introduced a "Sub-Category" system and am in need of modifying this code slightly. I found the following information to be very helpful:

[How to attach different events on multiple selectors through .on function in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756663/how-to-attach-different-events-on-multiple-selectors-through-on-function-in-jqu).

However, it doesn't quite solve my problem... I could use that to run two separate events for each selector within the same function but I need to run both simultaneously in the event both a "category" and "sub-category" are selected. Though they need to also be capable of running separate, in the event only one is selected. I'm fairly new to js/jquery so the more info you can provide the better! Thank you very much!

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('select#selectCategory').change(function()
        {
            var cat = $('select#selectCategory').val();
            var subcat

            if(cat > 0)
            {
                var param = '&category_id=' + cat;
            }else{
                var param = '';
            }
            var href = './videoroom.php?action=video_gallery'+ param +'&page=1';
            window.location.href = href;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Here is the HTML section related to the already written jquery code:

```
        <select style="min-weight:100px;" name="filter_by_cat" id="selectCategory">
                <option value="0">All</option>
                <option value="9">Wizard101</option>
                <option value="10">Pirate101</option>
                <option value="11">Pet Derby</option>
                <option value="14">Misc/Fun</option>
        </select>
```

And here is the new bit I added for the newly created Sub-Category:

```
        <select style="min-weight:100px;" name="filter_by_subcat" id="selectSubCategory">
                <option value="0">All</option>
                <option value="21">General PvP</option>
                <option value="22">PvPC Matches</option>
                <option value="23">PvP Guides</option>
                <option value="24">Miscellaneous</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Please post the HTML as well. And when applicable a jsFiddle.net example is helpful.

Comment: @j08691 Sorry about that, I've updated with the HTML.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been a little clearer. Please post the rendered HTML -- the PHP doesn't really pertain to the core question.

Comment: Where is the JS for the subcategories?

Comment: @j08691 My mistake, i should have thought about that... There we go fixed.

Comment: @raam86 In lies the issue... I'm not sure how to write it. The JS shown above is what was already there for categories. Since I've added subcategories I need a way to rewrite that function which will incorporate the design I described in the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the event listener to both dropdowns and check both of them when either is changed:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ug8Ap/)

```
$('#selectCategory, #selectSubCategory').change(function() {
    var cat = $('#selectCategory').val();
    var subcat = $('#selectSubCategory').val();

    var params = [
        'action=video_gallery',
        'page=1'
    ];

    if (cat > 0) {
        params.push('category_id='+ cat);
        if (subcat > 0) {
            params.push('subcategory_id='+ subcat);
        }
    }

    var href = './videoroom.php?'+ params.join('&');
    window.location.href = href;
});
```

I'm assuming you only want the subcategory choice to be taken into account when the main category is selected. If that's not the case, move the second if-statement outside the first one.

I also refactored your code a little to make it more easily extensible and (IMO) cleaner. I'm adding all the params to an array and them just joining them at the end. If you need to add any more params, just put them in the array as well.

Comment: You script fires on each select so I don't have a chance to choose subcat before I am redirected.

Comment: @raam86: Good point. The only way I can think of to get around that would be to provide a submit button, so the user can specify when they're done choosing options.

Comment: @Travesty3 I didn't get to see what your code looked like before the submit button addition. It would be ok to fire on each change so long as the opposing change is saved on the redirect. Though I think a better work around would be to only show the "category" drop down then once the category drop down is selected the "sub category" drop down would be provided. Then once the "Sub Category" drop down was selected it would automatically fire the redirect with both values without a submit button. Can this be done?

Comment: @RickMartin: I suppose that if the dropdowns will exist on the page you're redirecting to, you could do it that way. I suppose it would be OK as long as the page doesn't take too long to load. If you're suggesting to require the user to choose the subcategory before their query will be submitted, then you just need to have that event listener on the subcategory dropdown and not the other. Also, you can view the revision history by clicking the link in the bottom-middle that says when it was edited. Since that sounds like the solution you like better, I'll roll my edit back.

Comment: @Travesty3 Perfect... Following your advice I went ahead and changed the fiddle as you described. I made it to where each box also had a disabled selection so the user would realize they need to change both. Thank you very much for the help, this will work out nicely... http://jsfiddle.net/572qf/